# bash script optimization for big data

Tags: linux, bash, shell, optimization

I have the follogwing litte Skript that forms date.
The Problem i face is that the Skript is used for big data log files and it takes far to long.
I changed the for loop from read to cat because its faster. But the data program is still far to slow. How can I improve this ?

```
IFS='
'
for i in $(cat ist.log | egrep -o "^.{19}"); do 
        olddatum=${i}
        newdatum=`date -d "${olddatum}" +'%b %e %T'`
        echo ${newdatum} >> soll.log.fixed
done
```

Comment: what is the format of `olddatum` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the shell and `sed` and the `date` utility (most probably GNU `date`)

```sh
#!/bin/sh

search=$(sed "s/^\(.\{19\}\).*/\1/" file.txt)
replace=$(date -d "$search" '+%b %e %T')
sed "s/^$seach/$replace /" file.txt
```

---

With a while read loop using the shell. Don't read lines with `for`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r lines; do
 if [[ $lines =~ ^(.{19})(.+) ]]; then
   printf '%s %s\n' "$(date -d "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" +'%b %e %T')" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
 else
   printf '%s\n' "$lines"
 fi
done < file.txt
```